# A property of eigenvalues of the generators of a strongly continuous semigroup

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, delay-differential-equations

I am trying to read a book on Linear Delay Differential Equation, but I am getting stuck with some passages in some important proofs. I tried looking for alternative versions in Internet but couldn't find anything useful. Any help (or reference) is appreciated.

Let $\{T(t)\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+}$ be a strongly continuous semigroup of bounded linear operators, and let $A$ be its generator. Let us assume that $A$ is closed or bounded.

Let $\lambda\in\Bbb{C}$ be an eigenvalue for $A$, and let $\varphi,\psi:[-\tau,0]\to$ be such that $$(A-\lambda I)\varphi=\psi$$
and $$A\varphi=\varphi'$$
(that is, the semigroup $\{T(t)\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+}$ is the semigroup of the solution operators). The book says that from this two conditions we can derive that 
$$\varphi(\theta)=e^{\lambda\theta}\varphi(0)+\int_0^{\theta}e^{\lambda(\theta-s)}\psi(s) ds$$ for any $\theta\in[\tau,0]$. I really can't see why this should be true.

Comment: why can't you just solve $\phi'-\lambda \phi = \psi$?

Comment: Ok, I formulated my question badly.

Comment: If $A$ is the generator of a C0-S.G. it is automatically closed, you don't have to assume this. On which space is the S.G. defined? On $C_b$ with $A\varphi=\varphi'$ it is the S.G. of translations. You integrate $\psi$ from $0$ to $\theta$, this doesn't make sense if it is only defined on $[-\tau,0]$...